# Почему при подключении в SOAPHandler по EJB к WEBlogic теряется javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext при заходе в webmethod

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, glassfish, weblogic

Есть soap webservice c использованием JAXB

```
@WebService
@HandlerChain(file = "WebService_handler.xml")
public class WSservice {   

   @Resource
   private javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext wsContext; 

   @WebMethod(operationName = "Calculate")
   public ResultList сalculate(@WebParam(name = "parameter") InputParameters iparameters) throws DatatypeConfigurationException, Exception {       

            javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext messageCntx = wsContext.getMessageContext();  --NULLPOINTER
                             ......
         }
```

и SOAPHandler, в котором происходит подключение к weblogic по EJB

public class WebServiceMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler {

```
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext) {

    Hashtable hashTable = new Hashtable();  hashTable.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
    hashTable.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);    
    appContext = new InitialContext(hashTable);
    Object obj = appContext.lookup("TestingBean");                                            
    TestingBeanHome = (CarModelsHome)PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, TestingBeanHome.class);
                            ....
}
```

}

В SOAPHandler подключение к weblogic происходит, корректно отрабатывает,  SOAPMessageContex корректный до и после вызова подключения к EJB.
Но, когда я  захожу в веб метод @WebMethod(operationName = "Calculate"), происходит следующая ошибка при попытке получить wsContext.getMessageContext():

> Exception occurred in target VM:   java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>     at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.WebServiceContextImpl.getMessageContext(WebServiceContextImpl.java:86)
>     at webservice.wsauto.WSAuto.сalculate(WSAuto.java:69)   at

У кого-нибудь есть идеи почему теряется контекст? В какую сторону посмотреть?
Если в SOAPHandler не подключаться по EJB - контекст нормальный в вебметоде.